# A simple implementation of the Unix find command written in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm a C++ developer trying to learn Rust for fun and XP.
I decided to implement some of the Unix tools for practice.

Below is a simplified implementation of the `find` command.  The program takes 0 to 2 arguments: The first being the file to find, the second being the directory to start searching (I'm aware that the args aren't very robust).

I get the feeling there is a more succinct way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
use std::env;                                                                                                                                                                                  
use std::io;                                                                                                                                                                                   
use std::collections::VecDeque;                                                                                                                                                                
use std::ffi::OsString;                                                                                                                                                                        
use std::path::PathBuf;                                                                                                                                                                        
use std::process::exit;                                                                                                                                                                        

fn find(query: &String, start: &OsString) -> io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {                                                                                                                        
    let start = PathBuf::from(start);                                                                                                                                                          
    let mut dirs = VecDeque::from(vec![start]);                                                                                                                                                
    let mut result = Vec::new();                                                                                                                                                               

    while let Some(dir) = dirs.pop_front() {
        for entry in dir.read_dir()? {
            let path = entry?.path();
            if path.is_dir() {
                dirs.push_back(path.clone());
            }
            if let Some(name) = path.file_name() {
                if query.is_empty() || query.as_str() == name {
                    result.push(path.clone());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(result)
}
fn main() {
    let query = match env::args().nth(1) {
        Some(query) => query,
        None => String::new(),
    };
    let start = match env::args().nth(2) {
        Some(start) => OsString::from(start),
        None => OsString::from("."),
    };

    match find(&query, &start) {
        Ok(paths) => {
            for path in paths {
                if let Some(p) = path.to_str() {
                    println!("{}", p);
                }
            }
        },
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", err);
            exit(1);
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: @Ludisposed yes.  If I understand this correctly, it works because it is creating a copy of path (much like C++ would do implicitly).

Comment: Thanks @Ludisposed Do I need to do anything to avoid it being closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be simplified a little bit:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::ffi::{OsStr, OsString};
use std::io;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn find(query: &str, start: &OsStr) -> io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    let start = PathBuf::from(start);
    let mut dirs = VecDeque::from(vec![start]);
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    while let Some(dir) = dirs.pop_front() {
        for entry in dir.read_dir()? {
            let path = entry?.path();
            if path.is_dir() {
                dirs.push_back(path.clone());
            }
            if let Some(name) = path.file_name() {
                if query.is_empty() || query == name {
                    result.push(path.clone());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut args = std::env::args().skip(1);
    let query = args.next().unwrap_or(String::new());
    let start = args.next().map(OsString::from).unwrap_or(OsString::from("."));

    for path in find(&query, &start)? {
        if let Some(p) = path.to_str() {
            println!("{}", p);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

In your function `find`, [you should use the borrowed version of `String` and `OsString` as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or/40006220); or you can just move the value if you think that `query` or `start` will not be needed anymore in the main.

In you main, you can take advantage of the `Iterator`'s and `Option`'s methods to make a more concise and cleaner code:

- You create an iterator that will iterate over all args but the first using `skip`;
- The query is the next item: if there is no item, you give a default value with `unwrap_or`;
- For the next item, first you apply a function to the inner with `map`, and then you provide a default value;
- Your main can return a `Result`, so you do not need to make the error handling by hand.

Just a little thing: the idiomatic way to do such an algorithm in Rust is to implement an `Iterator`. In you code you do an unnecessary allocation for all your found files.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know about main being able to return a Result o_O
What about the calls to clone() on path.  I felt weird adding those calls in, but it seemed necessary to get rid of some move errors I was seeing.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting find() should return an Iterator instead of a Vec?  Sounds interesting!

Comment: About the first, I cannot summarize the ownership rules right now, but for this particular issue, if you hold a reference to a thing, you cannot move it because it'd invalidate the reference. You must clone it to have another item. And, yes, `find` should return an iterator.

Comment: @zachwhaley `Result` in `main` [was introduced in 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10). Here's [the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43301) if you're interested in the background.